# Can an Objective-C block object have an associated object?

Tags: objective-c-blocks

If it can, are there any gotchas to using it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can.  I just tried it.  This makes sense, since blocks are instances of `NSBlock` (a private class), which itself inherits from `NSObject`.

However, my naïve test seemed to indicate that the associated object was not un-associated when the block was deallocated.  (Although it's possible that I was never hitting the block's `-dealloc` method)

I'll keep experimenting and try some more stuff.

Comment: Interesting! Did you find anything more about this? Just curious. :)

Comment: @Dev I've since learned that associated objects are removed during final deallocation (so, like pretty much after everything else has already run)